# Python permutations including substrings

Tags: python, permutation

I've come across this post: [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

But I require something more, namely all of the permutations of a string as well as all the permutations of all the substrings. I know it's a big number, but is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273688/algorithm-to-generate-permutations-of-a-list-of-strings-and-their-substrings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import itertools

def all_permutations_substrings(a_str):
    return (
        ''.join(item)
        for length in xrange(1, len(a_str)+1)
        for item in itertools.permutations(a_str, length))
```

Note, however, that this is true permutations - as in, `hello` will have any substring permutation that has two `l`s in it twice, since the `l`'s will be considered "unique". If you wanted to get rid of that, you could pass it through a `set()`:

```
all_permutations_no_dupes = set(all_permutations_substrings(a_str))
```

Comment: You can iterate over them (e.g. `for result in all_permutations_substrings(...)`) or you can pass it to `list()` if you just want a list.

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi, you could do this: `result = [''.join(ele) for ele in set(all_permutations_substrings('hello'))]`

Answer (score 1):

As the question you linked states, [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is the solution for generating permutations of lists. In python, strings can be treated as lists, so `itertools.permutations("text")` will work just fine. For substrings, you can pass a length into itertools.permutations as an optional second argument.

```
def permutate_all_substrings(text):
  permutations = []
  # All possible substring lengths
  for length in range(1, len(text)+1):
    # All permutations of a given length
    for permutation in itertools.permutations(text, length):
      # itertools.permutations returns a tuple, so join it back into a string
      permutations.append("".join(permutation))
  return permutations
```

Or if you prefer one-line list comprehensions

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([["".join(p) for p in itertools.permutations(text, l)] for l in range(1, len(text)+1)]))
```